# How to click on a button using selenium Python ,if it's defined under <a> tag?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have been trying to make Python click on following button:

```html
<a id="likeSub2" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="openWin('https://www.subpals.com/network-v2/r/?https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QH7wiYT4OaU'); check(); startSub(); return false;" class="darken3" style="float:left;margin-top:2px;"><img src="https://www.subpals.com/network-v2/assets/images/button-like-subscribe.png"></a>
```

I tried using :

```
driver.find_element_by_id("likeSub2").click()
```

But it gives the obvious error.
I even Tried clicking on it using Class but it didn't workout
Thanks for replying
Ps:This Is my First Question here so pardon me If I go wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below options:
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@id='likeSub2']").click

OR

You can try hoovering your mouse (By using Action)and then click it might work. For this you have to import

from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
and create object
action=ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element().click